# Using jQuery, how can I store information in a dynamically created div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dynamic

I'm trying to create new objects from an attribute box with 'type', 'name' and 'number' text input fields. Ideally, you'd fill in the information, click create and a new object (100px by 100px box) would pop up.

Eventually, I'd like to get the text boxes to go blank when no object is selected, and then populate with the relevant info when one of the objects is selected.

Is there a way to store/retrieve information in a div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the **data** attribute

Setting Value

```
$(div).data('id','value');
```

Getting Value

```
var id = $(div).data('id');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use attributes of an element.

```
var $element = $('div.mydiv');
$element.attr('data-type', myType);
$element.attr('data-name', myName);
$element.attr('data-number', myNumber);
console.log($element.attr('data-type')); // Show how to get value back
```